# Python concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor max_workers

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give me some ideas how to achieve this.

When I use python module `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None)`, I want to know the `max_workers` how much the number of suitable.

I've read the official document.
I still don't know the number of suitable when I coding.

> Changed in version 3.5: If max_worker is None or not give, it will default to the number of processors on the machine, multiplied by 5, assuming that ThreadPoolExecutor is often used to overlap I/O instead of CPU work and the number of workers should be higher than the number of workers for ProcessPoolExecutor.

**How to understand "max_workers" better?**

For the first time to ask questions, thank you very much.

Comment: The default value is `os.cpu_count() * 5` which should be a good value but this may of course depend on your use case.

Comment: The quote somehow answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 10):

`max_worker`, you can take it as threads number.

If you want to make the best of CPUs, you should keep it running (instead of sleeping).

Ideally if you set it to None, there will be ( CPU number * 5) threads at most. On average, each CPU has 5 thread to schedule. Then if one of them falls into sleep, another thread will be scheduled.

Comment: What's the source on 5 threads per CPU? I thought a single physical CPU core could only support 2 threads?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the variable _max_workers

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
pool._max_workers
```