# What is the use case for limiting max_workers on concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

Is there any reason why you would want to specify the parameter for max_workers? Why would you not keep it set to None, the default? Is it ever faster to have less workers?

Comment: What about a scenario where you are trying to use parallel processing, but you don't want to tie up all of your available processor threads on a single task?

Comment: Related: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492894/python-multithreading-max-workers?noredirect=1&lq=1 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498288/number-of-max-workers-when-using-threadpoolexecutor-from-concurrent-futures/51043191#51043191 3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385479/python-concurrent-futures-threadpoolexecutor-max-workers Maybe someone will come and mark them as dupe?

Comment: @G.Anderson sure but if speed is the only factor, should you ever limit the amount of workers?

Comment: If speed _were_ truly the _only_ factor, then I can't think of a reason to limit it. However, in a real world scenario, I can think of several cases where that might not be the case, which is why the functionality needs to exist as an option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multithreading max\_workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492894/python-multithreading-max-workers)